# Parent.FrameName.FunctionName is not working in Mozilla

Tags: javascript

This is what I am having in the page

```
<frameset border="0" frameborder="0" frameSpacing="0">
        <frame name="banner" src="one.aspx?tab=" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
        <frame name="filter" src="two.aspx" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
</frameset>
```

and I am trying to call

```
Parent.filter.FuntionName.
```

This FuntionName is a javascript function which is in the one.aspx.

The issue is, this is working fine in IE while it is not working in MOZILLA. Is there any alternative for this statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the frames and find the one you want directly:

```
var frames = parent.getElementsByTagName('frame');
var frame = null;
for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; ++i)
  if (frames[i].name === 'two') {
    frame = frames[i];
    break;
  }

frame.FunctionName();
```

That'll work in IE too.